# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (reading 'classList') in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, undefined, typeerror

So apparently the draw() function towards the end of this code is the culprit for this error. I've seen other questions about this on here and my guess is the line below is overflowing or something?

> "blocks[currentPosition + index].classList.add('sonicBlock');"

But I still don't know what the solution to fix it is. FWIW I'm basing this off of this Tetris example: https://youtu.be/w1JJfK09ujQ?t=2424  She is trying to make CSS bg colored squares while I'm using img urls, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it? The imgs are 16px x 24px each. Thank you so much for anyone taking the time to look.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {


    //DEFAULT/CONST VALUES
    const fieldHorizontal = 16; //128
    const fieldVertical = 24; //192
    const width = 8;

    const blu = 0;
    const red = 1;
    const yel = 2;

    const container = document.querySelector(".activePlayField");
    const ScoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
    const StartBtn = document.querySelector('#start_button');

   

    const sonicColors = [
        'url(sonics/sonicblue.png)',
        'url(sonics/sonicred.png)',
        'url(sonics/sonicyellow.png)',
    ]



    //PIECES
    const piece_BBBB = [
        [sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu]],
        [sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu]],
        [sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu]],
        [sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu]]
    ]

    const piece_BBBR = [
        [sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[red]],
        [sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[red], sonicColors[blu]],
        [sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[red], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu]],
        [sonicColors[red], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu]],
    ]

    const piece_BBRR = [
        [sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[red], sonicColors[red]],
        [sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[red], sonicColors[red], sonicColors[blu]],
        [sonicColors[red], sonicColors[red], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu]],
        [sonicColors[red], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[blu], sonicColors[red]],
    ]



    const allPieces = [piece_BBBR, piece_BBBB, piece_BBRR]

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * allPieces.length);

    let currentPosition = 6;
    let currentPiece = allPieces[0][0];



    //
    function createGrid (n1, n2) {


        container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${n1}, 1fr)`
        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${n2}, 1fr)`

    
        for (let i = 0; i < (n1 * n2); i++) {
            let cell = document.createElement("div");
            cell.className = "cell";
            cell.id = `cell${i}`;
            container.appendChild(cell);
            
        }

    }

    createGrid (fieldHorizontal, fieldVertical); // draw play field grid

    let blocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cell'));


    function draw() {

        currentPiece.forEach(index => {
            blocks[currentPosition + index].classList.add('sonicBlock');
        })
    }

    draw();

 














})
```

```
body {
    background: rgb(207, 74, 196);
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

.activePlayField {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 128px;
    height: 192px;
    background-image: url("grid.png");
}
  
.activePlayField > div {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    opacity: 40%;

}

.sonicBlock {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 32px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    <script src="app.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Segasonic</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Score:<span id="score">0</span></h3>
    <button id="start_button">Start</button>
    
    <div class="activePlayField"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using .forEach the first parameter contains the current element of the array.

```
someValues.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

If you want to get the index of the current element. You should pass the index with a second parameter.

Try the following:

```
function draw() {

        currentPiece.forEach((element,index) => {
            blocks[currentPosition + index].classList.add('sonicBlock');
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have been the issue with it! Thanks :)